# Scaling up CALayer with sublayers leads to small gaps between sublayers

Tags: ios, calayer, catransform3d

**in short:**
I have a layer with many sublayers as tiles pixel perfect layed out on this superlayer. When the superlayer is scaled up (using UIScrollview, but internally with CATransform3D), the sublayers a scaled up with, but small gaps become visible between the tiles (sublayers)

**thesis:**
It is based on the little math inaccuracy using floats or doubles. This interpolated frames can't be displayed 100% correctly

It looks like the edges are interpolated.

What do you think can help? Do you need more details?

Comment: I've never run into math inaccuracy being a problem. Show us some code.

Comment: I thought of something like that, but in fact it was rather simpler. Check out the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: edge antialiasing!!!

If you enabled the flag in your Info.plist-file, you won't get precise edges, looking like gaps between tiles :-)

Hope that helps other people, too.